# Disabling non-clustered index on busy production database fails: Lock request time out period exceeded (Error: 1222)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing, non-clustered-index

I have a large and busy production database and I'm trying to tidy up the indexes that have accumulated over the years and reclaim some space. But I'm unable to drop/disable the existing indexes. They're all non-clustered yet disable fails with the below error and drop locks the table so I end up cancelling the statement after running for 5minutes.

> Lock request time out period exceeded. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 1222)

Any ideas? I'm sure I'm missing something very obvious but I was under the impression non-clustered indexes are metadata only so *should* be quick and easy to drop.

ETA - Follow up question - Is there any way I can lock the table to Management Studio manually so the drop run quicker?

Comment: Try using sp_who2 to find out what's blocking you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention RDBMS version, but assuming it is MS SQL SERVER 2012, DROP indexes ONLINE without locks on the table are allowed only for clustered indexes as in [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118(v=sql.110).aspx).

You're trying to drop an index but someone is using the table, so the LOCK TIMEOUT happens. I think you can drop the indexes only without someone accessing the relying table:

> Table locks are applied and the table is unavailable for the duration of the index operation.

Comment: It's SQL 2008, and online isn't an option for non-clustered indexes